# Make Fullpage-Scroll-Script less static

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

I got a little `Fullpage-Scroll-Script` and I want to make it a bit less static. So instead of calling every single `Div` by a different `Class` (.one, .two, .tree...) I want to make the script work if all `Divs` have only one `Class` (.page). I tried it myself with the `.each() function` from `jQuery` ... but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is the current `Script`:

```js
// Fullpage Scroll Script
function ScrollHandler(pageClass) { 
 var page = $('.' + pageClass);
 var pageStart = page.offset().top;
 var pageJump = false;

 function scrollToPage() {
  pageJump = true;
   $('html, body').animate({ 
   scrollTop: pageStart 
  }, {
   duration: 1000,
   easing:'swing',
   complete: function() {
    pageJump = false;
   }
  });  
 }
 window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  var viewStart = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (!pageJump) { 
   var pageHeight = page.height();
   var pageStopPortion = pageHeight / 2;
   var viewHeight = $(window).height();

   var viewEnd = viewStart + viewHeight;
   var pageStartPart = viewEnd - pageStart;
   var pageEndPart = (pageStart + pageHeight) - viewStart;
   
   var canJumpDown = pageStartPart >= 0; 
   var stopJumpDown = pageStartPart > pageStopPortion; 
   
   var canJumpUp = pageEndPart >= 0; 
   var stopJumpUp = pageEndPart > pageStopPortion; 

   var scrollingForward = event.deltaY > 0;
   if (  ( scrollingForward && canJumpDown && !stopJumpDown) || (!scrollingForward && canJumpUp   && !stopJumpUp)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    scrollToPage();
   }
  } else {
   event.preventDefault();
  }    
 });
}
new ScrollHandler('one'); 
new ScrollHandler('two');
new ScrollHandler('three');
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.page {
  height: 100vh;
}
.one { background-color: blue; }
.two { background-color: green; }
.three { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page one"></div>
<div class="page two"></div>
<div class="page three"></div>
```

So instead of using:

```
new ScrollHandler('one'); 
new ScrollHandler('two');
new ScrollHandler('three');
```

I tried to use this:

```
$('.page').each(function() {
  new ScrollHandler('page');
}
```

But it only worked for the first `Div`.

Comment: Can you also share what you have tried?

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive about what didn't work.

Comment: instead of 
new ScrollHandler('one'); 
new ScrollHandler('two');
new ScrollHandler('three');
i tryed this:
$('.page').each(function(){
new ScrollHandler('page');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$(this)` in each loop and change the page variable to get directly the parameter :

```js
// Fullpage Scroll Script
function ScrollHandler(pageClass) {
  var page = pageClass;
  var pageStart = page.offset().top;
  var pageJump = false;

  function scrollToPage() {
    pageJump = true;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: pageStart
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'swing',
      complete: function() {
        pageJump = false;
      }
    });
  }
  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    var viewStart = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (!pageJump) {
      var pageHeight = page.height();
      var pageStopPortion = pageHeight / 2;
      var viewHeight = $(window).height();

      var viewEnd = viewStart + viewHeight;
      var pageStartPart = viewEnd - pageStart;
      var pageEndPart = (pageStart + pageHeight) - viewStart;

      var canJumpDown = pageStartPart >= 0;
      var stopJumpDown = pageStartPart > pageStopPortion;

      var canJumpUp = pageEndPart >= 0;
      var stopJumpUp = pageEndPart > pageStopPortion;

      var scrollingForward = event.deltaY > 0;
      if ((scrollingForward && canJumpDown && !stopJumpDown) || (!scrollingForward && canJumpUp && !stopJumpUp)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollToPage();
      }
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
$('.page').each(function() {
  new ScrollHandler($(this));
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: blue;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page one"></div>
<div class="page two"></div>
<div class="page three"></div>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fw8h7v4q/